# Permission Denied error on NDK build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I could not run ndk-build. Getting this error. If someone can help.

**Terminal Output:**

C:\Users\Umair\Downloads\MaskItWithOpenCV\app\src\main\jni>ndk-build
C:\Users\Umair\Downloads\MaskItWithOpenCV\app\src\main/jni/Android.mk:11:                                                              C:/NVPACK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt /windows-x86_64: Permission denied
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/Users/Umair/Downloads /MaskItWithOpenCV/app/src/main/jni/ImageProcessing.cpp', needed by`C:\Users\Umair\Downloads\MaskItWithOpenCV\app\src\m
ain/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.o'.  Stop.

Comment: make sure C:/Users/Umair/Downloads /MaskItWithOpenCV/app/src/main/jni/ImageProcessing.cpp exists

Comment: Yes it exists. Any idea what could be the issue then ?